# Calling a class method into appDelegate gives funky notation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, appdelegate

So I got this code inside the update() function/method that tracks the game session in seconds (this is for achievement purposes) *If someone has a better way of doing this, I'm all ears*:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (pauseTimer == NO)
    {
        millisecondsTimer++;
        if(millisecondsTimer == 60) //Remember that SK runs at 60 FPS default which means 60 equals 1 second.
        {
            millisecondsTimer = 0; //Reset the counter to 0 to begin again.
            _secondsTracker++; //Add 1 second to this property.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Timer paused.");
    }
}
```

I want to take the _secondsTracker & save its value right before someone turns off the game completely (as in double clicks home button & swipes the game window up & away). The way I have it working now is using the appDelegate like so:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

BOOL pauseTimer;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GameScene.h" //For sessionTracker property.
#import "GameData.h" //To call upon gdTotalSessionTime property.


@interface AppDelegate ()

@end


@implementation AppDelegate


-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /*Override point for customization after application launch.*/
    return YES;
}


-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.*/
    /*Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.*/
    pauseTimer = YES; //Will stop the secondsTimer accumulating value.
}


-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.*/
    /*If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.*/

    //Will add secondsTracker value to the total (gdTotalSessionTIme).
    GameScene *gS = [[GameScene alloc] init];
    [GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds = [GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds + [gS.secondsTracker]; //Supposed to add the secondsTracker value to the gdTotalSeconds value.
    [[GameData sharedGameData] save]; //This saves all the data to a file in app.
    NSLog(@"THIS SESSION TIME: %ld seconds", gS.secondsTracker);
}


-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.*/
}


-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.*/
    pauseTimer = NO; //Will resume the secondsTimer value accumulation.
}


-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.*/
}
```

The line of code that's giving me problems is this one:

```
[GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds = [GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds + gS.secondsTracker;
```

More specifically `gS.secondsTracker`. Xcode keeps wanting to replace it into this:

```
*([GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds + gS.secondsTracker);
```

Doing so, nothing adds up the way I want it too & I know for a fact the `GameData` class is working correctly & saving other data to a file it created. Someone please tell me what these *() are?

Comment: post the class and code where you declare gS.SecondsTracker

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `GameScene`.  Why?

Comment: so what's the error of the original line? you only say that xcode wants to replace it, but not what error you get if you keep it.

Comment: Simply `[gS.secondsTracker]` should be `gS.secondsTracker`, which seems to be what you say Xcode wants

Comment: I'd say you're better off taking a start time and calculating delta times as a result of various triggers (like pause and done) instead of always counting

Comment: Truth be told, this is my first time calling methods from other classes in other classes. So I am not exactly sure how I am supposed to be calling them. GameScene *gS = [[GameScene alloc] init]; not correct before using GameScene's public secondsTracker property?

Comment: Don't you want the current / running `GameScene`?  You can probably add a singleton accessor to it as there is only ever going to be on instance of `GameScene`.

Comment: I'm going to try the singleton accessor (why didn't I think of that?).

Comment: @Krekin Please see my answer below; it's not *quite* a singleton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I advised that you can probably provide a singleton accessor to get hold of the currently running instance of `GameScene` it's not *quite* a singleton as you will want to allow `GameScene` objects to be created as normal.  What is required is simply accessing the "current" instance, with something like:

*header*

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene
...
+ (GameScene *)currentGameScene;
...
@end
```

*implementation*

```
static GameScene *_instance = nil;

@interface GameScene

- (instancetype)init...
{
    if (self) ...

    _instance = self;
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (self == _instance)
        _instance = nil;
}

+ (GameScene *)currentGameScene
{
    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Alright, I did as you showed - added the neccessary code to make my GameScene a singleton class. But I'm still getting problems with these 2 statements: [GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds = *([GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds + [GameScene currentGameScene].secondsTracker); [[GameData sharedGameData] save]; The game just crashes if I leave out of it & try to come back. It says this line is wrong: [GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds = *([GameData sharedGameData].gdTotalSeconds + [GameScene currentGameScene].secondsTracker);

Comment: @Krekin Why are you using `*(...)`?  What type is `gdTotalSeconds`?

Comment: Type long. Just like secondsTracker is type long.

Comment: @Krekin You don't need `*(...)`.

Comment: I agree, but when I take remove it, a warning keeps popping out. What is *(...) anyways?

Comment: @Krekin It's *dereferencing* the value so that will definitely make it crash.  To solve the warning I need to see it completely.